# wordpress posts template remove default template from menu

Tags: posts, templates

Im using wordpress custom post types for "resources"
The custom post type is called "**resource**"
Then I created 3 different "post templates" for the post type
webinars, news, gated content

Using different **POST TEMPLATES** for that.
everything works great there is just one thing I can't accomplish
need to **disable/remove** " Default Template" from the menu

[image]

and set "webinar" as the default one..

Comment: Why not just change the webinar template to the default template?

Comment: Looking in WordPress github, [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ae9eae8f64aa84b965ca1d67e13164826a493b52/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L991), there isn't an option to remove the default option, only change the text. What you can do, **NOT RECOMMENDED**, is to edit that core file (don't slap me for saying that), just take into account that next WordPress update your edit would be removed.

Comment: the default template is your `single-resource.php` file, couldn't you put the webinar template in there?

Comment: @Tom J Nowell
 I could but the client wants to display "Webinar"  in the admin instead of "Default Template"

Comment: @Buttered_Toast
I do want to change only the text  and of course don't want to change core files

Comment: In that case, you could hide that metabox and put your own in, assuming a filter doesn't allow it to be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change only the text you can hook into `default_page_template_title`

```php
add_filter('default_page_template_title', 'bt_change_default_page_template_title', 10, 2);
function bt_change_default_page_template_title ($text, $meta) {
    if ($meta === 'meta-box') return 'My custom template';

    return $text;
}
```

Add this code into `functions.php` and thats it.
Tested on a clean wordpress install, this will only change the text and nothing else, functionality will remain the same.

### Update

To get this filter to work with ACF we need to make a few changes.

1. ACF doesn't pass a second argument when using the filter so we need to assing a default value to our second parameter
2. Update our condition to take that new, empty, parameter into account

```php
add_filter('default_page_template_title', 'bt_change_default_page_template_title', 10, 2);
function bt_change_default_page_template_title ($text, $meta = '') {
    if ($meta === 'meta-box' || empty($meta)) return 'My custom templatee';

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: BTW it messed up my ACF metaboxes.. I just now see it  can I maybe limit it only to a certain CPT?

Comment: @gilhamer Updated my answer to include a working process that works with ACF as well

Comment: works great! thanks